# Android autocomplete suggests from internet

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I have to implement an EditText search field that, when the User is typing, it fetches suggestions from the internet and shows them in a drop-down menu.
I have read some doc stuff, and I've seen that there is AutoCompleteTextView class that realizes just this function, after setting a generic ArrayAdapter.
But in all the examples I've seen, the ArrayAdapter was filled with a static String array.
So I was thinking:
Is it simpler to use an EditText box and handle all the UI stuff on my own, or to use AutoCompleteTextView with an Adapter? In that case, will it correctly handle the changes of the suggestions array?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go ahead and use the autocomplete with Adapter option. You can easily do what you want by first taking the response from the net and then using it in a **handler for onTextChanged**. Implementing from scratch the GUI with edittext would be cubersome as well as time-consuming !!